# Python : Pandas how to skip bad lines with the 'python' engine

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am parsing an Apache log file and saving it into pandas data frame for my further investigation.

But in the log file I have some bad lines and so the following error occurs:

> ValueError: Expected 11 fields in line 4320, saw 27

To overcome this issue, I included `error_bad_lines = False` while reading the file. This doesn't help as I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: The 'error_bad_lines' option is not supported with the 'python' engine

**Note :**  I am explicitly using `python engine` as I have separator as a regular expression.

**Code snippet:**

```
data = pd.read_csv(
    log_file, 
    sep=r'\s(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)(?![^\[]*\])', 
    engine='python', 
    na_values='-',
    header=None,
    usecols = use_cols,
    skiprows =1,
    converters={time_taken_index[0]:parse_sec, time_index[0]:parse_datetime, req_index[0]:parse_str,status_index[0]:parse_str},
    error_bad_lines = False
    )
```

I'd be grateful for any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Could you attach a part of the log file you're talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using an old version of Pandas (<= 0.19.0).

The parameter `error_bad_lines = False` will work with the python engine in Pandas 0.20.0+.

So, just update the Pandas library.

Comment: That was the problem. The lower version of pandas did not support error_bad_lines for Python. However, I wasn't able to use it with C engine, any reason for that?

Comment: @AklankJain What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I am using pandas v0.21

Comment: I'm using pandas v0.24.2, updated to 0.25, the same error still there.